# What is the actual working implementation code used in double hashing a block header in c++?

Tags: mining-theory, sha256, c++

#### I need to successfully generate a hash value based on what i feel so far has been described as a hexadecimal filtered sha256 implementation... or something like that. I've been [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5110/how-does-a-miner-perform-hashing?rq=1) , [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50809/how-do-you-hash-data-for-mining?rq=1) , [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/51959/is-this-how-i-should-calculate-a-double-sha256?rq=1), [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/5671/how-do-you-perform-double-sha-256-encoding/100522#100522) and [here](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/102484/how-to-hash-block-header-in-c#:%7E:text=Firstly%2C%20you%20have,asLowerCase(hashString)%20%3C%3C%20endl%3B%0A%7D) ... amongst many other places.

---

Example Case:

Using "abc" as the input string,
[AnyHash.com](https://anyhash.com/sha256?abc) **with the 'Hex' checkbox ticked** produces a hash - **`15f27c6b8828e62cd3d09e8b4de5230844facfc88f1b9c34129cab7706f2f561`**. And when **`15f27c6b8828e62cd3d09e.......`** is fed as the input it produces the hash - **`42a5aa8cd08811f43428c42f76279a5a92e12b3e3f7080b87804a05135773487`**.

Following the [comment](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/50809/how-do-you-hash-data-for-mining?rq=1#:%7E:text=That%20code%20is,whatever%20you%20need%20*/) by [dave_thompson_085](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/26628/dave-thompson-085) i've been trying to make it work.
The sha256 implementation in use is the one provided by [Zedwood](http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-sha256-function) and below is my unfruitful struggle to recreate the hash output as generated by [AnyHash.com](https://anyhash.com/sha256?abc).

```
//  -----------------------                 --------------------------- //
//  -----------------------                 --------------------------- //
//  -----------------------                 --------------------------- //
// COMMENT BY DAVE_THOMPSON_085

// That code is okay except the silly std::string wrapper is useless for bitcoin. Do something like :
// unsigned char hdr[80], hash[32];
// SHA256 ctx = SHA256();

/* fill in hdr */
// ctx.init();
// ctx.update(hdr,80);
// ctx.final(hash);
// ctx.init();
// ctx.update(hash,32);
// ctx.final(hash);
/* (reverse and) use results in hash, possibly converted to hex or whatever you need */

//  -----------------------                 --------------------------- //
//  -----------------------                 --------------------------- //
//  -----------------------                 --------------------------- //

std::string sha256(std::string input)
{
    string kk;
    // header_data is "160" in size because midstate optimization is not implemented
    unsigned char header_data[160], hash[32];
    char hash2[32], hash3[32];
    char buf[2*32+1];
    buf[2*32] = 0;

    // input = GetBinaryStringFromHexString(input); // convert input data to binary format
    init();
    update((unsigned char*)input.c_str(), input.length());
    final(hash);

    // Iterate and store values from hash[] to hash2[]
    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++)
        hash2[i] = hash[i];

    // kk = final2(hash); // MODIFIED FUNCTION THAT RETURNS A STRING 
    // //kk = char_ToString(hash2); // Converts char array to string variable
    kk = GetBinaryStringFromHexString(char_ToString(hash2)); // convert data to binary format
    input = kk; // Store data in kk to input
    init();
    update((unsigned char*)input.c_str(), input.length());
    final((unsigned char *)hash3); // Modified as char* to unsigned char* conversion is not allowed


    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) 
        sprintf(buf+i*2, "%02x", hash3[i]); // ORIGINAL : sprintf(buf+i*2, "%02x", digest[i])

    return std::string(buf); // Return buf as string instead of char
}


int main(int argc, char const *argv[])
{
    std::string data = "abc";
    std::cout << "sha256(data) : " << sha256(data) << "\n";
    std::cout << "sha256(sha256(data)) :  " << sha256(sha256(data)) << "\n";
    return 0;
}

//  Input : abc
//  Expecting first hash output from sha256 ( with hex conversion ) to be :
// 15f27c6b8828e62cd3d09e8b4de5230844facfc88f1b9c34129cab7706f2f561 - single sha

//  And second output to be : 
// 42a5aa8cd08811f43428c42f76279a5a92e12b3e3f7080b87804a05135773487 - double sha

//  As generated byanyhash.com
```

It's always the obvious implementations that are sometimes the hardest to implement. - in my opinion.

The same hash generator **with the 'Hex' ticked** successfully generates the correct hash of [block 100000](https://www.blockchain.com/en/btc/block/000000000003ba27aa200b1cecaad478d2b00432346c3f1f3986da1afd33e506) existing in the bitcoin blockchain. [Block 100,000 hashed by AnyHash.com](https://anyhash.com/sha256?0100000050120119172a610421a6c3011dd330d9df07b63616c2cc1f1cd00200000000006657a9252aacd5c0b2940996ecff952228c3067cc38d4885efb5a4ac4247e9f337221b4d4c86041b0f2b5710)

Block header **`0100000050120119172a610421a6c3011dd330d9df07b63616c2cc1f1cd00200000000006657a9252aacd5c0b2940996ecff952228c3067cc38d4885efb5a4ac4247e9f337221b4d4c86041b0f2b5710`**

I tried getting the code from bitcoin source code **`hahahahahahahahahahahaha`.......** need i say more?

With so many headers included and dependencies beyond what is needed, just thinking about it was a nightmare. So please, if anyone knows how to actually make this code work... please assist a fellow programmer..

Lord knows all things bitcoin make most programmers look like a novice. A great technology nonetheless!

Below are the other functions used(in the event it has something wrong with it) Thanks in advance!

```
sing std::hex;

string GetBinaryStringFromHexString(string hexData);
// std::string char_ToString(char data[]);

std::string char_ToString(char data[])
{
    std::string stringData = ""; //declare string variable
    // int size = sizeof(data)/sizeof(*data); 
    int size =  strlen(data); //get amount of characters in char array
    for (int i = 0; i < size; i++) // for elements in char array
        stringData = data; // store elements in string variable "stringData"
    return stringData; // return stringData
}


string GetBinaryStringFromHexString(string hexData)
{
    string binaryResult = "";
    for (int i = 0; i < hexData.length(); ++i)
    {
        switch (hexData[i])
        {
        case '0':
            binaryResult.append("0000");
            break;
        case '1':
            binaryResult.append("0001");
            break;
        case '2':
            binaryResult.append("0010");
            break;
        case '3':
            binaryResult.append("0011");
            break;
        case '4':
            binaryResult.append("0100");
            break;
        case '5':
            binaryResult.append("0101");
            break;
        case '6':
            binaryResult.append("0110");
            break;
        case '7':
            binaryResult.append("0111");
            break;
        case '8':
            binaryResult.append("1000");
            break;
        case '9':
            binaryResult.append("1001");
            break;
        case 'a':
            binaryResult.append("1010");
            break;
        case 'b':
            binaryResult.append("1011");
            break;
        case 'c':
            binaryResult.append("1100");
            break;
        case 'd':
            binaryResult.append("1101");
            break;
        case 'e':
            binaryResult.append("1110");
            break;
        case 'f':
            binaryResult.append("1111");
            break;
        }
    }
    return binaryResult;
}
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Note that I am analyzing your code as if I compiled it as is. That means anything that is commented out is ignored.

---

The first major issue is this line:

```
    kk = GetBinaryStringFromHexString(char_ToString(hash2)); // convert data to binary format
```

The earlier `final(hash);` will have produced a char array filled with the SHA256 hash as binary data. Thus there is no need to convert that to a std::string and subsequently try to convert that to a binary string. This line is unnecessary and `hash` could be provided directly as input to the next `update()`. Fixing this should allow you to find the double SHA256 of `abc`.

The second major issue with this code is that `GetBinaryStringFromHexString` is not doing what you think it is doing. It is converting a string of hex to a string of binary. That is not the same as converting a string of hex to the binary data represented by that hex. What you actually end up with in that function is a much longer string whose data is the ascii characters for 0 and 1, not the data represented by the hex string itself. This [StackOverflow answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1968219) provides a hex string parsing function that you can use. Fixing this should allow you to find to find the double SHA256 of a block header that is provided as a hex string.

---

A couple of minor issues:

1. There is no need to duplicate `hash` to `hash2`. You can provide it directly as the parameter to the second `update` too.
2. There is no need to have `hash2` or `hash3`. You can use `hash` in `final` each time and it will be overwritten with the new hash.
3. The function `char_ToString` is not necessary. Besides that you don't need it for your code, `std::string` has a [constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) that can take a `char *` and its length.

---

Your final code would be something like:

```
std::string sha256(std::string input)
{
    string kk;
    // header_data is "160" in size because midstate optimization is not implemented
    unsigned char header_data[160], hash[32];
    char buf[2*32+1];
    buf[2*32] = 0;

    input = ParseHex(input);
    init();
    update((unsigned char*)input.c_str(), input.length());
    final(hash);
    
    init();
    update(hash, 32);
    final(hash);

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) 
        sprintf(buf+i*2, "%02x", hash[i]); // ORIGINAL : sprintf(buf+i*2, "%02x", digest[i])

    return std::string(buf); // Return buf as string instead of char
}

std::string ParseHex(const std::string& s)
{
    assert(s.size() % 2 == 0);
    static const std::size_t symbol_count = 256;
    static const unsigned char hex_to_bin[symbol_count] = {
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x00 - 0x07
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x08 - 0x0F
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x10 - 0x17
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x18 - 0x1F
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x20 - 0x27
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x28 - 0x2F
                 0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, // 0x30 - 0x37
                 0x08, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x38 - 0x3F
                 0x00, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x00, // 0x40 - 0x47
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x48 - 0x4F
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x50 - 0x57
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x58 - 0x5F
                 0x00, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x00, // 0x60 - 0x67
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x68 - 0x6F
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x70 - 0x77
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x78 - 0x7F
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x80 - 0x87
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x88 - 0x8F
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x90 - 0x97
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x98 - 0x9F
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xA0 - 0xA7
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xA8 - 0xAF
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xB0 - 0xB7
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xB8 - 0xBF
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xC0 - 0xC7
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xC8 - 0xCF
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xD0 - 0xD7
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xD8 - 0xDF
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xE0 - 0xE7
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xE8 - 0xEF
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xF0 - 0xF7
                 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00  // 0xF8 - 0xFF
               };

    std::string out;
    auto& itr = s.begin();
    while (itr != s.end())
    {
       unsigned char b = static_cast<unsigned char>(hex_to_bin[*(itr++)] << 4);
       b |= static_cast<unsigned char>(hex_to_bin[*(itr++)]     );
       out.push_back(b);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Comment: [You said](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/questions/111748/what-is-the-actual-working-implementation-code-used-in-double-hashing-a-block-he/111749#:~:text=This%20StackOverflow%20answer%20provides%20a%20hex%20string%20parsing%20function%20that%20you%20can%20use.%20Fixing%20this%20should%20allow%20you%20to%20find%20to%20find%20the%20double%20SHA256%20of%20a%20block%20header%20that%20is%20provided%20as%20a%20hex%20string.) .. Does that imply that i need a hex parser??    And if i do, where exactly will that parser be used? What is the simplified pseudo code according to your answer?

Comment: Also, the unnecessary `hash2` and `hash3` as well as the functions `char_ToString()` and `GetBinaryStringFromHexString()`  have been removed! The no. 3 on your list of minor issues clearly states that the ` char_ToString` is not necessary... I'm assuming that your reference to the [std::string constructor](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/string/basic_string/basic_string) is merely a reference to a more healthy and accurate approach - in the event that a conversion was actually required .

Comment: @AncientTides The hex parser function would be used where you currently have `// input = GetBinaryStringFromHexString(input);`, once you uncomment that line so you can try to hash the hex for a block header. I will edit with modified code.

Comment: Ran the edited code, it says **'ParseHex' was not declared in this scope**.   **`input = ParseHex(input);`** . I don't have the **`ParseHex();`** function you used. Could you please add it to your answer.... thanks

Comment: `ParseHex` is a placeholder for the hex parsing function from the stack overflow answer I linked. Figuring out how to actually use that function is left as an exercise for the reader.

Comment: Jesus Christ.. `hahahahaha`  ....... I just spent the last 13 days **exercising** this specific issue... Any more **exercise** and 3 years of work is going to go down the drain. With absolutely no commenting whatsoever, how am i in my current state of non-stop debugging going to understand [this code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1967460/c-hex-parsing/1968219#1968219).  Seriously man, you gotta help me here. Don't leave me hangin on this one.

Comment: Pleeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeaaaaaaaaaaaaassssssssssssssssssseeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeeee.............. Don't make a grown man cry!

Comment: I've added a `ParseHex` function that might work. I did not compile this code, but logically it should work.

Comment: Works like a charm [Andrew](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/48884/andrew-chow)....... WORKS LIKE A CHARM.

Answer (score 1):

Alright so it's been quite a ride on this specific task but Thanks to [Andrew Chow](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/48884/andrew-chow) there's finally a working version that I know a lot of newbies and even intermediate developers & programmers will surely find useful.

Had to make slight modifications to the **`ParseHex()`** provided by [Andrew Chow](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/48884/andrew-chow)....

### Headers needed are:

```
#include <string>
#include <cstring>
#include <assert.h> // assert() is used
```

**Sha256 implementation in use is the one provided by [Zedwood](http://www.zedwood.com/article/cpp-sha256-function) !!**

First is the **`ParseHex`** function provided by [Andrew Chow](https://bitcoin.stackexchange.com/users/48884/andrew-chow)

```
std::string ParseHex(std::string& s)
{
    assert(s.size() % 2 == 0);
    static const std::size_t symbol_count = 256;
    static const unsigned char hex_to_bin[symbol_count] = 
    {
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x00 - 0x07
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x08 - 0x0F
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x10 - 0x17
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x18 - 0x1F
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x20 - 0x27
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x28 - 0x2F
        0x00, 0x01, 0x02, 0x03, 0x04, 0x05, 0x06, 0x07, // 0x30 - 0x37
        0x08, 0x09, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x38 - 0x3F
        0x00, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x00, // 0x40 - 0x47
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x48 - 0x4F
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x50 - 0x57
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x58 - 0x5F
        0x00, 0x0A, 0x0B, 0x0C, 0x0D, 0x0E, 0x0F, 0x00, // 0x60 - 0x67
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x68 - 0x6F
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x70 - 0x77
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x78 - 0x7F
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x80 - 0x87
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x88 - 0x8F
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x90 - 0x97
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0x98 - 0x9F
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xA0 - 0xA7
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xA8 - 0xAF
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xB0 - 0xB7
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xB8 - 0xBF
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xC0 - 0xC7
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xC8 - 0xCF
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xD0 - 0xD7
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xD8 - 0xDF
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xE0 - 0xE7
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xE8 - 0xEF
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, // 0xF0 - 0xF7
        0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00  // 0xF8 - 0xFF
    };

    std::string out;
    auto itr = s.begin();
    while (itr != s.end())
    {
       unsigned char b = static_cast<unsigned char>(hex_to_bin[*(itr++)] << 4);
       b |= static_cast<unsigned char>(hex_to_bin[*(itr++)]     );
       out.push_back(b);
    }
    return out;
}
```

Then next is the modified **`sha256`** function call.

```
std::string sha256(std::string input)
{
    string kk;
    int size = input.length();
    
    unsigned char header_data[size], hash[32];// header_data is "160" in size because midstate optimization is not implemented
    char buf[2*32+1];
    buf[2*32] = 0;

    input = ParseHex(input); // ParseHex() is UNDEFINED !!!
    init(); // Initiialize
    update((unsigned char*)input.c_str(), input.length()); // Update
    final(hash); // Finalize

    // Uncomment code below if you want to directly double hash input data using a single "sha256(input)" function call
    // init();
    // update(hash, 32);
    // final(hash);

    for (int i = 0; i < 32; i++) 
        sprintf(buf+i*2, "%02x", hash[i]); // feed data from hash into buf and format data

    return std::string(buf); // Return buf as string instead of char
}
```

- **THESE FUNCTIONS NEED TO BE PASTED INSIDE THE SHA256 HEADER FILE**
- **YOU'D HAVE TO REVERSE ENDIANESS OF HASH RESULT.**
- **ALSO, THE "assert()" THROWS AN ERROR FOR UNEVEN LENGTHED INPUTS.. SO "abc" WON'T WORK.**

Hope this helps you if you ever need this....

Cheers